# How to send an Ajax request to a force.com visualforce page from our public domain Site.com site (across domains)?

Tags: visualforce, force.com, site.com, ajax, cors

We're trying to retrieve whether our service is available in particular zip codes. In Salesforce we have a custom object called "Service_Zone__c," each record of which has a zipcode and an "in"/"out" value for whether our service is available in that zone. I've written a small VisualForce page and controller that takes in a zipcode parameter, queries the Service_Zone object to see if that zipcode is "in" or "out", and outputs the result in JSON.

So our external application, running on a different domain (inside Site.com, btw) wants to send an AJAX query to this visualforce page. It sends the zipcode, and awaits the JSON back with the "in" or "out." But I run into CORS blocking my pinging the force.com query.

Comment: Why dont you create a rest webservice method which you can call from outside salesforce i.e different domain.

Comment: What's the best way to do that? And will we be able to call it from Site.com (where we have essentially no server-side code access)?